# working with form in Django

Tags: python, html, django

This is page that designed to submit the answers of my MCQ(multiple choice question) App in Django.

```
{% extends 'quiz/base.html' %}
{% block content%}
<h1>You are at quiz page</h1>

<form action="{% url 'quiz:process_data' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in question_set %}
        <h3>{{question.id}}.{{question.question_text }}</h3>
        {% for option in question.options_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="{{ option.options}}" > {{option.options}}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock%}
```

The problem is that it can only select the answer of one question. There is something wrong with my form. Thank you

Comment: You would use a <select multiple></select> form if you want to select multiple answers : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Thats how radio buttons work, they don't allow for multiple selection by design

Comment: You should be using Django's forms framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="{{ option.options}}">
```

by this line name of radio button will be same for each question. that's why  you are able to select only one answer. 
name of radio button should be different for diff. question

```
<input type="radio" name="choice{{question.id}}" value="{{ option.options}}">
```

you can use this code. In this name of radio buttons in first question will be    "choices1". and you can get selected option by

```
request.POST.get('choice1')
```

Comment: Bro ur answer is working perfectly but in the last part it is  choice1 instead of choices1. Thank u